# Undefined method/variable error, can't find cause

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, testing, railstutorial.org

I don't understand why authenticated? isn't false for a user with nil digest.
When I run the modeltest below I get the following error:

```
ERROR["test_authenticated?_should_return_false_for_a_stakeholder_with_nil_digest", StakeholderTest, 0.906488841]
 test_authenticated?_should_return_false_for_a_stakeholder_with_nil_digest#StakeholderTest (0.91s)
NoMethodError:         NoMethodError: undefined method `authenticated?' for nil:NilClass
            test/models/stakeholder_test.rb:126:in `block in <class:StakeholderTest>'
        test/models/stakeholder_test.rb:126:in `block in <class:StakeholderTest>'
```

This is the corresponding test (line 126 refers to the assert_not line):

```
  test "authenticated? should return false for a stakeholder with nil digest" do
    assert_not @stakeholder.authenticated?('')
  end
```

This is the authenticated? method:

```
  def authenticated?(remember_token)
    return false if remember_digest.nil?
    BCrypt::Password.new(remember_digest).is_password?(remember_token)
  end
```

Method as well as test have been literally adopted from Hartl's tutorial (only replaced user with stakeholder), so I don't understand what I could be doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the cause:
In def setup of the test file there was a typo, so that @stakeholder was undefined.